# How it works for DNS hostname without domain name in enterprise

Tags: dns, hostname

How can I set the following DNS setting for internal usage?

What's the setting method or distinguished name for this?

For example, I can type the following three url and all can find the same IP record.

> a -> 123.123.123.123
>
> a.test.com -> 123.123.123.123
>
> a.test.com.eu -> 123.123.123.123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client device needs to be provided with a set of DNS search domains to try.  These are typically deployed via DHCP.

Comment: Thanks,  search domains will list in "/etc/resolv.conf". And typically deployed via DHCP. Is that correct?